# C#: extract data from a collection and store it in an array

Tags: c#

I want to extract a data collection based on AID and store in a new collection have shared a sample data collection below as which create separate collection based on ID

```
  [
    {
        "id": 116,
        "AId": 168755,
        "Name": "Model1",
        "isRefDemand": false,
        "forecastType": "N-2",
        "prodQty": 0,
        "prodMonth": "2020/03",

    },
    {
        "id": 117,
        "AId": 168755,
        "Name": "Model1",
        "isRefDemand": false,
        "forecastType": "N-3",
        "prodQty": 0,
        "prodMonth": "2020/04",

    },
    {
        "id": 118,
        "AId": 168755,
        "Name": "Model1",
        "isRefDemand": false,
        "forecastType": "N-4",
        "prodQty": 0,
        "prodMonth": "2020/05",

    },

    {
        "id": 61,
        "AId": 168383,
        "Name": "Model2",
        "isRefDemand": false,
        "forecastType": "N-2",
        "prodQty": 0,
        "prodMonth": "2020/03",

    },
    {
        "id": 62,
        "AId": 168383,
        "Name": "Model2",
        "isRefDemand": false,
        "forecastType": "N-3",
        "prodQty": 0,
        "prodMonth": "2020/04",

    }
    ]

want to retrive and store as 
        {

        "AId": 168755,
        "Name": "Model1",
        "isRefDemand": false,
        "forecastType":
        {
        "forecastTypeN-2":"N-2",
        "forecastTypeN-3": "N-3",
        "forecastTypeN-4": "N-4",
        }
        "prodQty":
        {
        "prodQty0": 0,
        "prodQty1": 0,
        "prodQty2": 0,
        }

    },
    {


        "AId": 168383,
        "Name": "Model2",
        "isRefDemand": false,
        "forecastType":
        {
        "forecastTypeN-2": "N-2",
        "forecastType1N-3": "N-3",
        }
        "prodQty":
        {
        "prodQty": 0,
        "prodQty1": 0,
        }

    },
```

Comment: What problem do you have with doing that? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq GroupBy is what you need to solve this. Group on AID then project the grouped items to a new collection, e.g:

```
 var items= new List<MyItem>()
            {
                new MyItem() { id = 116, AId = 168755, Name = "Model1", forecastType = "N-2", prodQty = 0 },
                new MyItem() { id = 117, AId = 168755, Name = "Model1", forecastType = "N-3", prodQty = 0 },
                new MyItem() { id = 118, AId = 168383, Name = "Model2", forecastType = "N-2", prodQty = 0 },
                new MyItem() { id = 119, AId = 168383, Name = "Model2", forecastType = "N-3", prodQty = 0 }
            };

            var itemsGrouped = items.GroupBy(t => t.AId).Select(x => 
                new
                {
                    Aid = x.First().AId,
                    Name = x.First().Name,
                    isRefDemand= x.First().isRefDemand,
                    forecastType = x.Select(i => i.forecastType),
                    prodQty = x.Select(i => i.prodQty),
                }
                ).ToArray();
```

This retrieves the first item in a group to populate the single properties and all the items in a group to select from to populate the list properties.

Add any more single properties you need to the projection by calling First(), same as shown for AID.

Example assumes class is defined like:

```
 public class MyItem
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int AId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool isRefDemand { get; set; }
        public string forecastType { get; set; }
        public  int prodQty { get; set; }

        public DateTime prodMonth { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly achieve this with Linq to Sql .GroupBy()

Please follow below article to take a look on how you can use groups in C#

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/how-to-group-multiple-array-of-object-in-c-sharp

Comment: He doesn't want LINQ to SQL, he just wants to use LINQ. Group By isn't an EF Core specific function nor does this question involve a database.

Comment: I have suggested an example to use LINQ in C# either with or without SQL. 
So, i believe using only LINQ library will solve his problem, as he can use it to applying Group functions for json objects and arrays as well.